# Formatting a .cshtml with WPF

Tags: wpf, razor, template-engine, razor-2

I have a Razor template which I want to format with a model (a custom DTO) to return a string. I'm doing this from WPF, so I don't have an HttpContext. So far, the closest I've come is https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide but when I call `Execute()`, I just get the name of the template file.

I'm sure this is possible but I can't get the syntax right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Spark, and wrote a quick blog post - [Templating with Spark and WPF](http://www.leghumped.com/blog/2012/12/28/templating-with-spark-and-wpf/).

Comment: What's public ViewDataDictionary ViewData { get; set; }?